# Как телеграм боту получить id только что отправленного им же сообщения

Tags: python, telebot

Желательно без get_updates ()[-1]. Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотек для работы с телеграм для питона несколько. Не зная, какую именно вы используете отвечу в общем. Telegram API предоставляет метод [messages.sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage), который возвращает данные об отправленном сообщении. Среди этих данных в том числе идентификатор отправленного сообщения.

Скорее всего библиотека которую вы используете также возвращает эти данные. Тогда код будет примерно таким:

```
res = bot.sendMessage(chatId, "текст сообщения")
print(res.id)
```